# If $E$ is a closed set, prove that $\partial E \subset \partial \partial E$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

> If $E$ is a closed set, prove that $\partial E \subset \partial \partial E$.

Take $x \in \partial E$. Now by definition $\partial E= \overline{E} \setminus \operatorname{int}(E).$ But since $E$ is closed $\overline{E} = E$ so $x \in E$.

Now $\partial \partial E= \overline{\partial E} \setminus \operatorname{int}(\partial E) \subset \overline{\partial E} = \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{cl}(E) \setminus \operatorname{int}(E)) \subset \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{cl}(E)) = \operatorname{cl}(E) =E $

So $\partial \partial E  \subset E$ and since $x \in E \implies x \in \partial \partial E $.

Is the reasoning here correct?

Comment: Are you assuming that $cl(A\setminus B) =cl(A)\setminus cl(B)$? Also , the last implication is obviously wrong.

Comment: No that’s a mistake. I’ll correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you show that $\partial E$ is closed, this answer is immediate using the definition you gave.

Can you see why $\partial E= \overline{E}\cap \big( int(E) \big)^c$ is closed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a definition management (handling ) exercise.

**Hint**. By definition, $x\in \partial E$, it means that
$$
 ( \forall r >0)(\exists u\in E) ( \exists v\in E^{c})(u,v\in B(x,r))
$$
and by definition, $y\in \partial\partial E$, it means that
$$
 ( \forall \rho >0)(\exists \alpha\in \partial E) ( \exists \beta\in (\partial E)^{c})(\alpha,\beta\in B(y,\rho))
$$